# Show that $H = \{g ∈ G : \hbox{|g| is finite}\}$ is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to prove the following,
Suppose $G$ is an Abelian group. Show that $H = \{g ∈ G : |g|\ \hbox{is finite}\}$ is a subgroup.
I know that to prove a subset is a subgroup one can prove $ab^{-1} \in H$ for all $a,b \in H$ but I'm not sure how to apply that for this problem.

Comment: Note that the fact $G$ is an Abelian group. It is not difficult to check that $ab^{-1} \in H$ for any $a, b \in H$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

(i)$|g|=|g^{-1}|$ for every $g\in G$

(ii) If $G$ is abelian, then $|ab|$ divides $|a||b|$ if $a$ and $b$ are of finite order.

Indeed, $H$ is known as *torsion subgroup* of $G$.